# How to design individual commutation for SCRs in H Bridge configuration?

Tags: power, power-electronics, thyristor

I am designing a DC drive using SCRs in H bridge(with protection circuits). Triggering is done via an optocoupler.
Motor specifics:24V DC , 10 Amps
Supply specifics: 24 V DC, 15 Amps(with regulation, protection)
SCR switches are specifically preferred by the application for reliability and robustness in high temperature.So I have preferred them over MOSFETs and IGBTs for my H Bridge design.Moreover, the machine for which the drive is designed is structurally designed for SCRs, with heat sinks specifically for individual SCRs

Comment: Assuming your supply really is DC, how will your SCRs ever turn off - or am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah, you aren't missing anything. Most commutation techniques taught at college focus on commutation of a single SCR using discharge of a RC /LC circuit. However that does not work here.My intern employer has given me this problem

Comment: *I am designing...*  but your title says: *How to design...*. So basically you're doing something but don't know how to do it. Why not have a look at all designs made on earth sofar ? There might be some out there you can use. You've decided to use SCRs but I bet no one does that because there's a fundamental problem with that. See brhans's comment. Also **why** SCRs ? Do they also ask interns to go and buy snake oil as well at this company ?

Comment: I checked quite a lot of books and sources.I would be glad if you can suggest something. I understand that usually people use IGBT or MOSFET for the design. However, here the issue is not of controllability in general. The issue is that my employer has specifically got some manufacturer to develop an SCR which works at temperatures of about 200 degree Celsius. The MOSFETs with such specs are nearly at their limits

Comment: Include that in your question and suddenly the question makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie - these days there is no reason to use SCRs (at least for small to moderate size drives) but they were used a lot in the past before IGBTs became available.

Comment: I have a book that describes, in 17 pages, a DC chopper circuit using SCRs. The book was published in 1964. If you don't have the resources to find that kind of material, I don't know how you can manage what you are trying to do.

Comment: Is the DC smooth or is it full-wave rectified AC without smoothing? If the latter then SCRs might work.

Comment: @Transistor, I believe it is a rectified ac from an SMPS. I would like to have some ideas on how it could work.

Comment: @Charles Cowie, I would like to know the title of the book. Secondly, I really don't know whether just making any DC chopper circuit using SCRs might work. The author might have implied SCR behaviour as a switch while demonstrating chopper action

Comment: The SMPS almost certainly has smoothing capacitors. Even if it didn't the frequency would probably be too high for SCR control.

Comment: I tried natural commutation, with inverter circuits for obtaining pulsated dc, with PWM supply

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic SCR chopper circuit that is described in detail in B. D. Bedford & R. G. Hoft, *Principles of Inverter Circuits*, John Wiley & Sons, 1964. It is in an Appendix by W. McMurray.

[image]

Forced commutated SCR circuits with switching frequencies up to about 400 Hz have been successfully used in products. Such products were successful in some applications for a short time. They were not very efficient, so they produced a lot of heat. It was very difficult to make them rugged and reliable. It was difficult and expensive to get SCRs with sufficiently short turn-off time specifications. The dv/dt of reapplied voltage was a problem.

Here is a diagram of a reversible DC motor drive using a saturable reactor in the commutation circuit. TRC is time ratio control. I think that is the same as PWM. The circuit is probably described in: W. McMurray, "Analysis of thyristor DC chopper power converters including nonlinear commutating reactors," in IEEE Transactions on Magnetics, vol. 6, no. 1, pp. 16-21, Mar 1970.
doi: 10.1109/TMAG.1970.1066710

The commutation circuit is described here: R. E. Morgan, "Basic Magnetic Functions in Converters and Inverters Including New Soft Commutation," in IEEE Transactions on Industry and General Applications, vol. IGA-2, no. 1, pp. 58-65, Jan. 1966.
doi: 10.1109/TIGA.1966.4180615

[image]

Comment: Thanks Charles. I will try this and get back to you if it is working and if some modification is required.We tried something similar yesterday, however, our design had an extra diode across the LC oscillator  to provide reverse current

Comment: The large number of inductors unfortunately doesn't agree with my employer's requirement of having a small PCB profile!

Comment: If you still want to pursue the use of SCRs in this application, I believe there is a scheme in which a single LC circuit is used to reverse the voltage of the DC bus after C1. An inductor is required in series with the DC supply after C1 to isolate the supply during the 30 microseconds or so the the bus voltage is reversed. That would still cut the inductor count in half. Only one commutation capacitor would be required. I believe that two additional capacitors would be needed for the commutation circuit.